# django-notifications: how NOTIFICATIONS_SOFT_DELETE=True works?

Tags: django, python-2.7, notifications, django-notification

I want a notification system for my app, so I was looking into a django package called django-notifications. I understood all of it but NOTIFICATION_SOFT_DELETE=True settings.

I mean when I do the following:

```
from notifications import notify
notify.send(user, recipient=user, verb='you reached level 10')
```

This will make an entry to the database with `deleted=False` if I am not wrong. I have the following in my `settings.py`:

```
NOTIFICATIONS_SOFT_DELETE=True
```

which updates to `deleted=False` to `deleted=True`. But I don't know when this change happens. There is one API in documentation which marks all notifications as `deleted=True`:

> **qs.mark_all_as_deleted() | qs.mark_all_as_deleted(recipient)**
>
> Mark all notifications in the queryset (optionally also filtered by
>   recipient) as deleted=True. Must be used with
>   NOTIFICATIONS_SOFT_DELETE=True.

**but how to mark some notifications to be `deleted`??**

Answer (score 1):

here is the offical documents:

> **Soft delete**
>
> By default, `delete/(?P<slug>\d+)/` deletes specified notification record from DB. You can change this behaviour to "mark Notification.deleted field as True" by:
>
> Add to your settings.py: `NOTIFICATIONS_SOFT_DELETE=True`
>   With this option, QuerySet methods unread and read contain one more filter: deleted=False. Meanwhile, QuerySet methods deleted, active, mark_all_as_deleted, mark_all_as_active are turned on. See more details in QuerySet methods section.
>
> **`qs.mark_all_as_deleted() | qs.mark_all_as_deleted(recipient)`**
>
> Mark all notifications in the queryset (optionally also filtered by recipient) as `deleted=True`. Must be used with `NOTIFICATIONS_SOFT_DELETE=True`.

so, if you want to mark some notifications to be deleted,you can do either of these

1. at frontend just call API of `delete/(?P<slug>\d+)/`
2. at backend query notifications and call `mark_all_as_deleted()` or `mark_all_as_deleted(recipient)`

Answer (score 0):

**This is all you need.**

After installing django-notifications-hq and added 'notifications' as an app to your installed app in settings.py and added **url('^inbox/notifications/', include(notifications.urls, namespace='notifications'))** to your url patterns.

MAKE sure you then install django-notifications-rest and then install  'notifications_rest' as an app next to the one you added as above. Then also add   **url('^notifications/', include('notifications_rest.urls'))** if you are using django v3.0 and below or if you are using v3.1 and above add  **path('^notifications/', include('notifications_rest.urls'))** under urlpatterns in your url file.

Then **python manage.py makemigrations**. This will create a rest endpoint which you can access on **http://localhost:8000/notifications**. It is from this end point through your frontend like react you can send an api request to get all unread requests and then mark all requests as read after an onclick event by sending another request through the api.

**http://localhost:8000/notifications/all/ will return all requests
http://localhost:8000/notifications/unread/
http://localhost:8000/notifications/delete/22 will delete request with id 22
http://localhost:8000/notifications/mark-all-as-read/ will mark all requests as read** among all other endpoints you can access.

But i believe in this case, use **http://localhost:8000/notifications/unread/** to get all unread requests on page load and then onclick, use **http://localhost:8000/notifications/mark-all-as-read/** or **http://localhost:8000/notifications/delete/22** to remove or reduce notifications respectively.