# Django-notification delete API from front-end

Tags: django, django-notification

Can you please help me about django-notification???
I am able to implement it, but stuck in delete from front end using this API

**delete/(?P\d+)/**
what I suppose to provide in place of **(?P\d+)/** , when I call this API

Comment: The `id` to delete.

Comment: please add the code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

ID is basically notification ID , and problem is that we first convert it using slug function then pass to API, Here is the code of id conversion

```
def id2slug(id):
    return id + 110909
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.delete, name='delete'),

def delete(request, id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
  if request.is_ajax():
    member = Member.objects.get(id = id)
   member.delete()
   messages.info(request, 'Member was deleted successfully!')
return JsonResponse({'data': 'bar'})
```

for more details https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thanks for quick replay, but python implementation is already done by module developer, I am just call API from front end, as I provide id in API call it return 400 error,
Here is refrence to URL calls
https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications/blob/master/notifications/urls.py

and here is the API call methods
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45457260/3796988

Comment: This is my ajax call
$.ajax({
                       type: 'GET',
                       url: "/inbox/notifications/delete/" + msg["id"] + "/",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data)
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
                            {#setInterval(sendRequest, 15000); // The interval set to 5 seconds#}
                        }
                    });
error
GET <ip>/delete/20/ 404

Comment: url: '/inbox/notifications/delete/" + msg["id"]' ,

Comment: add like urls.py  url(r'^inbox/notifications/delete/(?P<id>\d+)$',

Comment: error is this
http://127.0.0.1:8000/inbox/notifications/delete/16/ 404 (Not Found)

previous is short due to comment words limit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164150/discussion-between-syed-imran-hassan-and-gowthaman).

Answer (score 0):

From the readme on github : https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications,we can see that the value is not the id thats which it dose not delete when you pass in the id as the 'slug'.

urls.py (from the source code)
...
`pattern(r'^delete/(?P<slug>\d+)/$', views.delete, name='delete')`
...

Each Notification has a slug property in the Notifications model which you pass to the delete api to delete the notification.